# Looping input and finding average of list when q is inputed

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function in python that repeatedly asks for input and once the string 'q' is entered it breaks the loop and returns the average of the input. I have no idea why this isn't working.

```
def listave(list):
    UserInput = input('Enter integer (q to quit):')
    list.append(UserInput)
    while UserInput != 'q':
        UserInput = input('Enter integer (q to quit:)')
        if isinstance(UserInput, int) == True:
            list.append(UserInput)
        elif UserInput == 'q':
            break
    list.pop()
    print('Average: ', float(sum(list) / len(list)))

listave(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't `pop` from list. There is no need to because you never append `'q'` to `list` anyways. Second, you need to convert to an `int` after you get input, otherwise the `isinstance` will never work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues in your code.  First, `list` is a built-in definition, it is not a good practice to overload it's definition.

You use `pop`, but there is no reason for it.  The values of '`q`' is not added to the list.

Lastly, `input` always returns a string.  So you will need to convert it to a number before appending to the list.

Here is a modification of your code that tries to convert the input to a float, unless `'q'` is the input.  If it cannot, it prints a message and continues.

```
def listave(my_list):
    UserInput = ''
    while UserInput != 'q':
        UserInput = input('Enter integer (q to quit:)')
        if UserInput == 'q':
            break
        try:
            x = float(UserInput)
            my_list.append(x)
        except ValueError:
            print('Only numeric values and "q" are acceptable inputs')
    print('Average: ', float(sum(my_list) / len(my_list)))

listave([])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify answer to match the original code. This is more pythonic version. As a next level, this can also be written using `atexit`.

```
def avg():
    l = []
    while True:
        i = input("Enter integer (q to quit:) ")
        if i.strip() == "q":
            a = float(sum(l))/ len(l)
            print("Average: ", a)
            return a
        else: 
            try:
                l.append(float(i))
            except ValueError:
                print('Only numeric values and "q" are acceptable inputs')

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    avg()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to import from `functools`, you can use the `partial` class and the `iter` function, which can take a sentinel argument to tell the iterator on which input to terminate.

```
from functools import partial

def listave(list):
    UserInput = iter(partial(input, 'Enter integer (q to quit):'), 'q')

    for inp in UserInput:
        try:
            list.append(int(inp))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    print('Average: ', float(sum(list) / len(list)))

listave(list)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're running Python 2, make sure you're using `raw_input()`, instead of `input()` (in Python 3 you should always use `input()`)

```
def get_average():
    ls = []
    user_input = 0
    while user_input != 'q':
        user_input = raw_input('Enter inter (q to quit):')
        if user_input != 'q':
            ls.append(int(user_input))
        elif user_input == 'q':
            break
    ls.pop()
    return sum(ls), ls

print get_average()

# ls.pop() will delete the last number of input
```